# Dependency rules in a root eslint config

Tags: eslint

I have 2 projects with different `.eslintrc` config files. I created a root config file which merges all common rules. My issue is that my projects' rules have some rules based on dependencies like `"@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types"`.

My assumptions is it doesn't work from my root directory because it has no `package.json`/`node_modules` or some relevant files.

How do I make it work so that I could define this rule in my root directory?

My frontend code ignores the rule and complains about explicit-module-boundary-types. It works when I move the rule back to frontend's `.eslintrc`.

Here's my directory hierarchy:

```
project-root
├── frontend
│   ├── .eslintrc.json
│   └── .package.json
├── backend
│   ├── .eslintrc.json
│   └── .package.json
└── .eslintrc.json
```

root `.eslintrc` config

```
{
  "root": true,
  "rules": {
     "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types"
  }
}
```

frontend `.eslintrc`

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "prettier"],
  "extends": [
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": "off",
  }
}
```